# Making a menu of tables in php

Tags: php

Ok what I am trying to make is a system that supports tickets. Tickets have all kinds of info on a specific job. How can I make a ticket menu with like links to tickets which contain all the info I need. For instance I click on ticket number 777 so it I have the php?id=777 in the url.

I need this page to constantly look for new tickets.

Comment: Are you looking for HTML or PHP code? What I mean is, are you looking for help in designing the page, or designing the server back-end?

Comment: I need both I suppose. I can make a simple result page that shows tables but not one that is always updated with links to those tables.

Comment: Then you're looking for JavaScript with AJAX. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: Somewhat yes. I thought it was able to be done with just php and html

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is add a the correct ticket to an anchor

```
<a href="page.php?id=777">Ticket 777</a>
<a href="page.php?id=778">Ticket 778</a>
```

on the page.php you can access the ticket number using the `$_GET` variable

```
<?php
   $ticket = $_GET['id'];
   /// now you have the ticket number in the variable
?>
```

Comment: Does page.php have to be actual pages?

Comment: No all custom. Is there anyway I can just link the ticket ID to just the information to the ticket?

Comment: are you using a database? i suggest u go to [this site](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627-PHP-101-PHP-For-the-Absolute-Beginner), you will get more information

Comment: Yup. I connect to it and enter values through html form.

Answer (score 0):

`I need this page to constantly look for new tickets.`

I'm not 100% sure what you're exactly looking for here, but there are two basic solutions here:

- AJAX to update the content without reloading the page
- Reload the page every few minutes and have PHP handle it

The first is better for things that are constantly updated, like Twitter posts, news, stock-tickers, etc, but it's a little overkill for something that updates relatively rarely (takes longer than 6 minutes or so).

The tickets should be stored in some kind of database and then read out and looped over to create the table. This would probably make more sense in a list format (stacked divs) instead of a table, but then again, I don't know the specifics.

For the simple PHP generation of links, @Ibu has a good example.

EDIT:

For more information about implementing AJAX, [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) has a good example. I would recommend using a framework like jQuery or MooTools to handle the AJAX because there are some inconsistencies between browsers.

EDIT:

From the comments you made, it sounds like you are not very familiar with how PHP works.

PHP is just a templating language with some programming language features. It is best used to generate pages on the fly with dynamic content from a database.

When you try to request a `.php` page, you are actually telling the server to execute the code in that file. When all the code is finished, the resulting document is given to the requesting browser. The result should be valid HTML if done correctly.